# Multiply 20 different static values by 12, based on the value that the user is choosing and display the total after

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea is (take a look at the picture below), I try to display a label (bottom right corner in the image) with the total/ year of a service choosen by the client. As you can see [image where you can maybe understand better what I try to say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7ioo.png).

[image]

In these 2 columns I have 2 different services for the client, in the column 2 for example when the client is choosing 2 licenses(orange bar/gray bar) he can see the total (per month) of those 2 licenses right below. And I would like to take that total and multiply it * 12 (to have the total / year) in a different label, and I want to use the same idea for every number between 1 - 20.

Firstly I wanted to use the id of the **total/month** which is a dynamic value and multiply it by 12 to have the **total/year**, but I haven't succeeded to make it work. So I would like to try something more static and have a condition for every case possible between 1-20.

Ex: 10$ = 1 license, the client is choosing 5 licenses so it would be a total of 50$ / month, I want to take this value and multiply it by 12 and display it after.

The more static way idea it would be if the user is choosing any number of licenses between 1-20, I would like to have an IF condition for each of the possibilities, when the user clicks 4 display the monthly price multiplied by 12 in a different label.

Here are the IDs of that might help you and the jQuery part of code that I tried to make it work.

```
 <span id="annuelPricesTotal">Total : </span>
```

id of the Total / year (right bottom corner in the img)

```
<span value="text" class="priceAnnuel" id="annual-standard-total-price">Total :</span>
```

ID of the Total / Month

```
  var theBeforeTotal = 0;
  var priceTotalAnnual = (14.90 + (9.90 * 11)).toFixed(2).replace(".", ".") + '€HT/Annuel';
  $('#standardSliderAnnual').click(function () {
    // console.log($(this).val(priceTotalAnnual));
    theBeforeTotal = Number($(this).val(priceTotalAnnual));
    $('#annuelPricesTotal').html("Total: " + theBeforeTotal);
  });
  $('#annuelPricesTotal').html("Total: " + theBeforeTotal);
```

The jQuery I tried, where I tried to implement the following idea, when the user accessed the page for the first time the Total/Year button should show 0 inside, and just after the user clicks the columns it should show the total/ year, I know that the function for calculating the total/ year is not good.

```
  <input id="standardSliderAnnual" type="range" name="foo" min="1" max="20">
```

There is the id of the input that user will use to choose the amount of licenses he wants, 1-20.

Comment: It's not clear at all. You can license up to 20 users. First user costs e.g. 14.90, each other 9.90? Then why do you calculate 11*9.90, i.e. first month 14.90 and rest of the year 9.90?

Comment: My mistake there, the first license is 14,90. If you want to purchase more than one will cost 9.90/ license, that's why. And about the formula that I have used as I said it's incorrect, I want to have the total /month which is calculated following this idea for example let's say I want 3 licenses. First month 14.90 + (9.90x2) = X, after I want to multiple that X * 12, to have the Total / year. I hope it's clearer now.. sry. (The X represents the amount of money that a person has to pay / month for N amount of users (between 1-20).

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the problem, you could calculate a base fee (first user fee - second user fee) plus a fee per each user, the first as well. HTML5 specifies `data-` attributes as valid custom attributes. So we can hold this data in HTML.

The `input` event is fired immediately after the value of the `<input>` element has changed, in opposit to the `change` event which is only fired when the input is complete (e.g. focus lost after changing the value).

To improve performance we define the event listeners as closures having access to pre-queried collections and preparsed DOM data.

```js
$(()=>
{
  let
    $annualTotal = $('#annual-total'),
    totalFees    = [0,0,0]
  ;

  function currencyFormat(value)
  {
    return value.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' });
  }

  function calcAnnualTotal()
  {
    $annualTotal.html(currencyFormat(12 * totalFees.reduce(function(sum, current) { return sum+current; }, 0)));
  }

  $('#licenses>div.licence').each(function(idx, div)
  {
    let
      $slider = $(div).find('input.standardSliderAnnual'),
      $total  = $(div).find('.total')                    ,
      baseFee = parseFloat($(div).attr('data-base-fee')) ,
      perUser = parseFloat($(div).attr('data-per-user')) ,
      onInput = function()
      {
        totalFees[idx] = parseInt($slider.val()) * perUser + baseFee;
        $total.html(currencyFormat(totalFees[idx]));
        calcAnnualTotal();
      }
    ;

    $slider.on('input', onInput);
    onInput();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="licenses">

  <div class="licence" data-base-fee="0" data-per-user="2.99">
    <h2>License 1</h2>
    <input class="standardSliderAnnual" type="range" name="foo" min="1" max="20" value="1">
    <div>
      <span>Total: </span><span class="total">0,00 €</span><span>HT</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="licence" data-base-fee="5" data-per-user="9.9">
    <h2>License 2</h2>
    <input class="standardSliderAnnual" type="range" name="foo" min="1" max="20" value="1">
    <div>
      <span>Total: </span><span class="total">0,00 €</span><span>HT</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="licence" data-base-fee="10" data-per-user="14.9">
    <h2>License 3</h2>
    <input class="standardSliderAnnual" type="range" name="foo" min="1" max="20" value="1">
    <div>
      <span>Total:</span> <span class="total">0,00 €</span><span>HT</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Annual Total</h2>
    <div>
      <span id="annual-total">0,00</span><span>HT</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: EDIT* I implemented it already and it works fine. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet excample basing on your layout.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Tiregan/Lub8jg74/2/

```js
init();

function init() {
  service = 0;
  users = 0;
  
  selectService(0);
  addListenersServices();
  addListenersSliders();
}

function recount(serviceNumber) {
  if (serviceNumber === '0') {
     ; 
  } else if (serviceNumber === '1') {
    users = $('#range-option-1').val();
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(Math.round((2.99 + users * 2.99) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    $('#total-monthly-1').text(totalPrice);
  } else if (serviceNumber === '2') {
    users = $('#range-option-2').val();
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(Math.round((14.90 + users * 9.90) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    $('#total-monthly-2').text(totalPrice);
  } else if (serviceNumber === '3') {
    users = $('#range-option-3').val();
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(Math.round((24.90 + users * 14.90) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    $('#total-monthly-3').text(totalPrice);
  }
}

function selectService(serviceNumber) {
  $('.option-main').removeClass('selected');
  $('#main-' + serviceNumber).addClass('selected');
}

function addListenersServices() {
  $('.service').click(function(){
    var serviceNumber = this.id.replace('service-', '');
    service = serviceNumber;
    
    selectService(serviceNumber);
    recount(serviceNumber);
  });
}

function addListenersSliders() {
  $('.slider').on('input', function() {
    sliderNumber = this.id.replace('range-option-', '');
    
    if (sliderNumber === service) {
        recount(service);
    }
    
  });
}
```

```css
.option-main {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  border: 1px #999 solid;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  margin: 0 0.4vw 0 0.4vw;
  min-width: 13vw;
  width: 13vw;
  min-height: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
}

.option-main a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-up {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px grey dashed;
  height: 70%;
  padding-top: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 2.3vw "Arial";
  color: darkred;
}

.main-down {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: silver;
  height: 30%;
  padding-top: 0.8vw;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 1vw "Arial";
  color: dimgray;
}

.option-secondary {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  border: 1px #999 solid;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  margin: 0 0.4vw 0 0.4vw;
  min-width: 13vw;
  width: 13vw;
  min-height: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 1.3vw "Arial";
  color: #444;
}

.secondary-table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.secondary-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  width: 70vw;
  clear: both;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  width: 80%;
  height: 0.4vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slider::-moz-range-progress {
    background-color: orange;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8.4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
    background: #3071a9;
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  height: 1vw;
  width: 1vw;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -0.3vw; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; 
    background-color: orange;
}

.slider::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%:
}

.span-font-normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.selected {
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="row">
  <a id="service-0" class="service" href="#">
  <div id="main-0" class="option-main seleceted" href="#">
    <div class="main-up"></div>
    <div class="main-down"></div>
  </div>
  </a>
  <div id="main-1" class="option-main" href="#">
      <a id="service-1" class="service" href="#"><div class="main-up">0.00€</div></a>
      <div class="main-down">
        Needs extra users?<br>
        <input id="range-option-1" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0">  
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main-2" class="option-main" href="#">
    <a id="service-2" class="service" href="#"><div class="main-up">14.90€</div></a>
    <div class="main-down">
        Needs extra users?<br>
        <input id="range-option-2" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0"> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main-3" class="option-main" href="#">
    <a id="service-3" class="service" href="#"><div class="main-up">24.90€</div></a>
    <div class="main-down">
        Needs extra users?<br>
        <input id="range-option-3" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0"> 
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <a class="option-secondary" href="#">
      <div class="secondary-table">
        <div class="secondary-cell">
          FREE
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="option-secondary" href="#">
      <div class="secondary-table">
        <div class="secondary-cell">
          2,99 €HT / user<br>
          <span class="span-font-normal">- - - - - - - - - - - - -</span>
          Total: <span id="total-monthly-1">2,99</span> €HT
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="option-secondary" href="#">
       <div class="secondary-table">
        <div class="secondary-cell">
          14,90 €HT<br>
          <span class="span-font-normal">- - - - - - - - - - - - -</span><br>
          + 9,90 €HT / user<br>
          <span class="span-font-normal">- - - - - - - - - - - - -</span>
          Total: <span id="total-monthly-2">2,99</span> €HT
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="option-secondary" href="#">
      <div class="secondary-table">
        <div class="secondary-cell">
          24,90 €HT<br>
          <span class="span-font-normal">- - - - - - - - - - - - -</span><br>
          + 14,90 €HT / user<br>
          <span class="span-font-normal">- - - - - - - - - - - - -</span>
          Total: <span id="total-monthly-3">2,99</span> €HT
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="console"></div>
```